# who is hitting the requests of Azure function /admin/functions error

Tags: azure-functions

we have a azure function and we observed an error where azure function is trying to hit an non-existent api /admin/functions.
we have not configured any trigger or exposed any api of type /admin/functions.
why do we seeing this error and who is hitting with this function /admin/functions.

How can we stop this requests /admin/functions hit.

Comment: Any details of this error? Can you show the log?

Comment: we are getting this hit with this url "http://{azure-function-appservice-url}:80/admin/functions" - not sure why we are getting this hit,is it default from azure ,how can i disable this default settings.

Comment: Where did you get the error? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: we are getting this error in our  azure appinsights, i am unable to share screenshot.